# Silicon Controlled Switch Problem

Tags: circuit-analysis, breadboard, silicon

Can someone correct me and help me draw this SCS circuit diagram for a breadboard before I do the actual circuit? I tried using Multisim but since I'm new to it, it was hard for me to do so.

[image]

Comment: What is SCS? I don't think the circuit will work too well - the 9V source is across the base-emitter junction of the 2n3904. This will clamp it to one diode drop. I'd suggest you research your circuit and get it correct before moving forward.

Comment: Just a note that if you build that, the NPN transistor will most likely burn up since it incorrectly connected directly to the battery. What is the circuit supposed to do?

Comment: It looks like an erroneous attempt at a thyristor using discrete components. Again, what is SCS?

Comment: Silicon Controlled Switch?? Haven't seen one of those referred to since the 70's.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an LTspice simulation showing a synthetic thyristor working:

[image]

I've replaced the two mechanical switches with voltage-controlled switches S1 and S2 that are actuated for 1ms at 100ms and 200ms respectively.

I've brought the power supply voltage up with a controlled (10us or 0.9V/us) ramp to start off with the switch in the 'off' state.

R4 is necessary to keep the 10M\$\Omega\$ leakage in the switches from triggering the thyristor.

You will notice I've moved the supply connection so the 9V does not destroy Q1, and made a couple other small changes.

The purple trace represents the current through the LED- it turns on at 100ms and off at 200ms.

The green trace illustrates a problem with this circuit- the Vbe breakdown\$\text V_{(BR)EBO}\$ of the 2N3906 is only guaranteed to be 5V, and is typically around 7-9V. In this case you can see that it sees 8.1V while the switch is activated. A lower supply voltage or an added base diode would be prudent.

Comment: By 'breadboard' the assumption is the white plastic things that you push wires into? There's the online Fritzing tool that should assist you. as you really don't want us to do your homework do you?

Comment: @user294753, you will learn a lot more if you do this yourself. Find a good breadboard layout tool (Fritzing?) and post update your question adding in the corrected schematic and your breadboard attempt. Just make sure you understand which breadboard sockets are interconnected. It's very simple.

Comment: I think this is really your job to figure out, and as others say you will learn much more by figuring it out yourself.

Comment: Thank you good lads!

Answer (score -1):

Silicon controlled switches shared billing with silicon controlled rectifiers in 1960's versions of the GE Transistor Manual. The manuals explained their operation saying that transistor beta is dependent on current levels. The (conceptual) transistors in the devices had betas less than unity for leakage current levels. They were made that way. 2N3904s and 2N3906s aren't. They can be made to work like an SCS, with external circuitry, but it takes some work and might not pass a worst-case analysis. Whatever you're trying to do there must be an easier way. Also, you should be skeptical of simulated results. I had a painful experience trying to get a Spice forerunner to simulate a thyristor as cross-connected transistors. The Ebers-Moll model it used insisted that gain is fixed, not current dependent.